# Issue making .exe with Pyinstaller : compilation is done but the .exe fails

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, pyautogui

I have a rather large python script that I would like to convert to .exe. I use PyInstaller and I managed to import every library needed so now I don't get any error message. My problem is that at some point, the .exe is stuck, so the conversion with PyInstaller didn't really worked. I suspect the issue is related to the PyAutoGui library, but I had to import it to convert my python script (I used pip install).

Does anyone else got the same issue? Is there something I can do to remove this issue?

I have python 3.9.2 and pyinstaller 4.2 and I am working with windows 10.

The libraries I had to import are : pyautogui, pandas, bs4, pygame, PyQt5, pywin32, winshell, pymysql, sqlalchemy, sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator, wmi, Pillow, psutil and lxml.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, PyInstaller has had trouble generating .exe files from python scripts that use graphics libraries such as pygame and PyQt5. Mostly, it fails to generate the .exe and even when it does, the .exe takes a long time to load up and is really slow. If you want an .exe file, I would suggest trying out [cx_freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). To my knowledge, it won't generate .exe in one file like pyinstaller does, but the .exe file it does generate is of much higher quality.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! PyInstaller seemed more accessible than cx_freeze, and my colleague was eventually able to make it work on his computer using auto-py-to-exe, but we didn't really pay attention at what we downloaded or changed to make it work... I will try to look a bit more into cx_freeze!

Answer (score 0):

We think we found the issue: pyautogui needs an other package called open-cv to work. Hope it'll help someone someday ;-)